# AWS SAM - get error message : pywintypes.error: (5, 'CreateFile', 'Access is denied.')

Tags: python, aws-sam-cli

When i run the following command :

sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction --event ./events/event.json

i get the following message :

pywintypes.error: (5, 'CreateFile', 'Access is denied.')

im attempting to run a lambda\python locally but i get the above error message

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? I am having the same issue

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get a fix for this issue.  i decided to use serverless framework to run local lambdas

Answer (score 2):

The problem here lies in docker requiring you to have admin privileges whilst executing the commands SAM Local is sending to it. Normally, you would solve this issue by launching a powershell as admin. You should be able to run `sam local start-api --debug` in this mode.

However, what you usually want is to be able to use this together with vscode, and in order to do that, you have to do a workaround, consisting of the following:

- Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS
- Create an environment variable called `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375`
- If you're behind a corporate proxy, you also need to set an environment variable `NO_PROXY=localhost`, so that your proxy doesn't interrupt
- (I don't know if this is necessary): I also installed Sam Local on a different folder from the default `C:/Program Files`, in order to avoid putting the installed software in an admin protected folder.

Another option (which I haven't checked out myself) that should be possible is to add your user to the docker-user group. As I don't know much about this option, I'll just leave this hint as-is here.

In any way, you can check that this works by running `sam local start-api --debug` in your sam project folder. You should now also be able to run the local debugging tool from vscode:

[image]

I know that this doesn't answer your question exactly, but I hope that this helps anyone with similar issues coming from google!